# What is the expected number of white balls, conditionally, in each row of this grid of white and black balls?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have an $m\times n$ grid of black balls, $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, and I randomly switch $k$ of them to white, where $1 \leq k \leq mn$. Every possible configuration of $k$ white balls is equally probable.

I want to compute the expected number of white balls in any row containing *at least one* white ball.

When $mn \gg k$, I can appeal to the fact that $p_0$, the probability that any given row contains no white balls, is approximately $\left(1-m^{-1}\right)^k$, hence the expected number of rows containing no white balls is $E[n_0] \approx mp_0 = m\left(1-m^{-1}\right)^k$, leaving $k$ white balls in the remaining $$E[n_{>0}] = m - E[n_0] = m - m\left(1-m^{-1}\right)^k$$ rows. The expected number of white balls in each of these rows can therefore be approximated $$E[n_{\text{white}}|n_{\text{white}} \geq 1] \approx k\left(m - m\left(1-m^{-1}\right)^k\right)^{-1}$$

However, as $\phi = \frac{k}{mn}$ increases towards $1$, this approximation becomes increasingly inadequate.

Comment: @quasi: I don't know whether a closed form exists, but I assumed one likely does since the problem statement is relatively simple. I'm constantly amazed by the probability questions on M.SE that wind up having closed form expressions. If you could post your Maple code, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{mn}{k}$ ways to select the cells with white balls, all of which we assume are equally likely.

First, what is the probability that row $i$ contains at least one white ball, for $1 \le i \le m$? It is $1$ minus the probability that the row contains no white balls, i.e.
$$P(\text{at least one white ball}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{mn-n}{k}}{\binom{mn}{ k}}$$
Second, what is the probability that row $i$ contains at least one white ball and cell $i,j$ contains a white ball?  This is the same as the probability that cell $i,j$ contains a white ball:
$$\frac{k}{mn}$$
Let's define $X_{ij} = 1$ if cell $i,j$ contains a white ball, given that row $i$ contains at least one white ball, $0$ otherwise. Then
$$E(X_{ij}) = P(X_{ij} =1) = \frac{k / mn}{1 - {\binom{mn-n}{k}} /{\binom{mn}{ k}}}$$
By linearity of expectation, the expected number of white balls in row $i$, given that the row contains at least one white ball, is
$$\begin{align}
E \left( \sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij} \right) &= \sum_{j=1}^n E(X_{ij}) \\
&= n E(X_{ij}) \\
& = \frac{k / m}{1 - {\binom{mn-n}{k}} /{\binom{mn}{ k}}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: A very clear explanation. Thank you. One small caveat is that when $n(m-1) \leq k \leq nm$, then $P(\text{at least one white ball}) = 1$ exactly.

Comment: @COTO We consider $\binom{mn-n}{k} = 0$ when $mn-n < k$, so there is no need to make an exception.